# My JavaScript file is linked, but JavaScript code is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

My JavaScript file is linked and also working, I came to know this when i linked the `.js` file, i made an `alert("working");` and it was working but when i did further coding it didn't work.

Then i tried on google chrome console (image is attached), it started working. Why the `.js` file is responding at first but not working afterwards.

```
document.querySelector("button").AddEventListener("click", handleClick);

function handleClick(){
        alert("I am Clicked!!!");
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Drum Kit</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

        <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
        <div class="set">
                <button class="w drum">w</button>
                <button class="a drum">a</button>
                <button class="s drum">s</button>
                <button class="d drum">d</button>
                <button class="j drum">j</button>
                <button class="k drum">k</button>
                <button class="l drum">l</button>
        </div>

        <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <footer>
                Made with ❤️ in London.
        </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It should be `addEventListener()` not `AddEventListener()`

Comment: Open the console. Read the error messages. You made a typo. `AddEventListener` should be `addEventListener`

Comment: `querySelector` is only going to add the event listener to the first element which matches the selector -> So, only the first button is going to fire the event even after you fix your typo : (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). If you need to fire this click event on all the buttons, use `querySelectorAll` and then iterate the collection adding an event listener to each button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors:

1. If should use `addEventListener` not `AddEventListener`:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener('click',handleClick)
function handleClick(){
        alert("I am Clicked!!!");
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
     <button class="w drum">w</button>
     <button class="a drum">a</button>
     <button class="s drum">s</button>
     <button class="d drum">d</button>
     <button class="j drum">j</button>
     <button class="k drum">k</button>
     <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>
```

2. Your code will only work for the first button, if you want to apply the function to all buttons you need to use `querySelectorAll` and loop over the list to add the event listener to every button as follows:

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll("button");
for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++)
     btns[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick)
function handleClick(){
        alert("I am Clicked!!!");
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
<div class="set">
     <button class="w drum">w</button>
     <button class="a drum">a</button>
     <button class="s drum">s</button>
     <button class="d drum">d</button>
     <button class="j drum">j</button>
     <button class="k drum">k</button>
     <button class="l drum">l</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The matter is that my code is not even working for the first button using an external JavaScript file but when i use the same code on chrome console, it worked.
Now, the matter might be that i might have not linked the external JavaScript file properly, for that purpose i commented the JavaScript file and run a simple alert("Hi i am working!!"); and it was showing an alert with that message. This means that the JavaScript file is linked properly but the code is not working...

Comment: Please link your code to a fiddle in order to help you debug your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with your `query selector`. You selected all buttons with one `querySelector`. When you selected all the buttons with a `querySelectorAll` the `eventListener` only works on the first element. So I've created a `for loop` that loop trough all buttons.

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for (var i = 0 ; i < btn.length; i++) {
   btn[i].addEventListener('click' , handleClick) ; 
}

function handleClick(){
        alert("I am Clicked!!!");
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
        <div class="set">
                <button class="w drum">w</button>
                <button class="a drum">a</button>
                <button class="s drum">s</button>
                <button class="d drum">d</button>
                <button class="j drum">j</button>
                <button class="k drum">k</button>
                <button class="l drum">l</button>
        </div>

        <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <footer>
                Made with ❤️ in London.
        </footer>
```